# read string data from excel and sort it in alphabetical order in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, sorting

I am reading string data from different Excel files, each file contain three column. I merged the columns and I want to remove the match data and sort it and alphabetical order. I used the code below. It works well. However, the data did not come in alphabetical order. Here is my code

```
[~,newtext]=xlsread('d1.xlsx');
[~,newtext1]=xlsread('d2.xlsx');
[~,newtext2]=xlsread('d3.xlsx');
[~,newtext3]=xlsread('d4.xlsx');
%%
d1=newtext;
d2=newtext1;
d3=newtext2;
d4=newtext3;
C=vertcat(d1,d2,d3,d4);
%%
for i22=1:size(C,2)
    if(strcmp(C{1,i22},'Extracellular_matrix')==1)
        for j22=1:size(C,1)-1
            Extracellular_matrix(j22,1)=C(j22+1,i22);
        end
    end
end
[ECM_Node,~,x] =unique(sortrows(Extracellular_matrix(~cellfun('isempty',Extracellular_matrix))));
ECM_Node=cellstr(ECM_Node);
```

Could anyone help in this issue?

Here is my data:

```
Extracellular_matrix    Apoptosis   Inflammation
ABI3BP  AAMDC   ABCA1
ACHE    AARS    ABCC8
ADAM10  ABR ADAM10
ADAM15  ACAA2   AGT
C6orf15 ANXA6   F3
CAPG    APAF1   FGF2
CAPN1   APBB1   GABPA
CAPN2   APBB2   GAL
CCDC80  APC GCNT2
CCL21   APH1A   GJB1
CD151   APH1B   HMOX1
CD248   APIP    ICAM1
CD36    APLP1   IDO1
CD44    APOH    IL13
CDH1    AQP1    IL1A
CDON    AR  IL1B
COL3A1  ASNS    MMP9
COL4A1  ATF2    MYD88
COL4A2  ATF3    NF1
COL4A4  ATF4    NFKB1
COL5A1  ATG4D   NOV
```

Thanks in advance
output:

```
'ABI3BP'
'ACHE'
'ADAM10'
'ADAM15'
'ADAM9'
'ADAMTS1'
'ADAMTS12'
'ADAMTS2'
'ADAMTS3'
'ADAMTS4'
'ADAMTS5'
'ADAMTS9'
'ADAMTSL1'
'ADAMTSL2'
'ADAMTSL3'
'ADGRG1'
'ADGRG6'
'AEBP1'
'AGRN'
'AGT'
'ALB'
'ANGPTL4'
'ANTXR1'
'ANXA2'
'ANXA2P2'
'APBB1'
'APBB2'
'APCS'
'APLP1'
'APLP2'
'APOH'
'ASPN'
'ATP7A'
'B4GALT1'
'B4GALT7'
'BCAM'
'BGN'
'BMP1'
'BMP4'
'C6orf15'
'CAPG'
'CAPN1'
'CAPN2'
'CCDC80'
'CCL21'
'CD151'
'CD248'
'CD36'
'CD44'
'CDH1'
'CDON'
'CFDP1'
'CFP'
'CHI3L1'
'CHL1'
'CLASP1'
'CLASP2'
'COCH'
'COL11A2'
'COL12A1'
'COL14A1'
'COL15A1'
'COL1A1'
'COL1A2'
'COL3A1'
'COL4A1'
'COL4A2'
'COL4A4'
'COL5A1'
'COL5A2'
'COL6A1'
'COL6A2'
'COL6A3'
'CPXM2'
'CREB3L1'
'CRIP2'
'CRISP3'
'CRISPLD2'
'CRTAC1'
'CSGALNACT1'
'CST3'
'CTGF'
'CTHRC1'
'CTSD'
'CTSK'
'CTSL'
'CTSS'
'CTSV'
'CYP1B1'
'CYR61'
'DCN'
'DDR2'
'DGCR6'
'DLG1'
'DMBT1'
'DPP4'
'DPT'
'DST'
'ECM1'
'EFEMP1'
'EFEMP2'
'EFNA5'
'ELF3'
'ENAM'
'ENG'
'ENTPD1'
'ERBIN'
'ERO1B'
'ETS1'
'F3'
'FAP'
'FBLN1'
'FBLN5'
'FBLN7'
'FBN1'
'FGA'
'FGB'
'FGF10'
'FGF2'
'FGF9'
'FGFR2'
'FGFR4'
'FGG'
'FKBP1A'
'FLRT3'
'FMOD'
'FN1'
'FRAS1'
'FREM2'
'FSCN1'
'FURIN'
'GAS6'
'GFOD2'
'GLG1'
'GPC2'
'GPC3'
'GPC4'
'GPC6'
'GPM6B'
'GPX1'
'GREM1'
'GSN'
'GSTO1'
'HAPLN4'
'HAS2'
'HMCN1'
'HMCN2'
'HNRNPM'
'HPN'
'HPSE'
'HSD17B12'
'HSP90AA1'
'HSP90AB1'
'HSPG2'
'HTRA1'
'ICAM1'
'ICAM2'
'IGFBP7'
'IL1RL1'
'IMPG2'
'ITGA11'
'ITGA2'
'ITGA3'
'ITGA4'
'ITGA5'
'ITGA6'
'ITGA8'
'ITGAX'
'ITGB2'
'ITGB3'
'ITGB4'
'ITGB8'
'JAM3'
'KDR'
'KIF9'
'KLK7'
'KLKB1'
'LAD1'
'LAMA2'
'LAMA3'
'LAMA4'
'LAMB1'
'LAMB2'
'LAMB3'
'LAMC1'
'LAMC2'
'LAMC3'
'LCP1'
'LGALS1'
'LGALS3'
'LGALS3BP'
'LMCD1'
'LOX'
'LOXL2'
'LPL'
'LTBP1'
'LTBP2'
'LUM'
'LYPD3'
'LYPD5'
'MAMDC2'
'MATN2'
'MEGF9'
'MELTF'
'MFAP1'
'MFAP2'
'MFAP4'
'MFGE8'
'MGP'
'MIA3'
'MMP1'
'MMP10'
'MMP12'
'MMP14'
'MMP15'
'MMP16'
'MMP19'
'MMP2'
'MMP3'
'MMP7'
'MMP9'
'MMRN2'
'MPZL3'
'MUC4'
'MYO1E'
'NAV2'
'NCL'
'NDNF'
'NF1'
'NFKB2'
'NID1'
'NID2'
'NOTCH1'
'NOV'
'NPNT'
'NTN4'
'NYX'
'OGN'
'OLFML2B'
'OPTC'
'P3H2'
'P4HA1'
'PCOLCE'
'PDGFA'
'PECAM1'
'PHLDB2'
'PI3'
'PLAT'
'PLG'
'PLSCR1'
'PODN'
'POSTN'
'PRDX4'
'PTPRZ1'
'PXDN'
'RARRES2'
'RELN'
'RGCC'
'RIPK3'
'SEMA5A'
'SERPINA1'
'SERPINB5'
'SERPINE1'
'SERPINE2'
'SERPINF1'
'SERPINH1'
'SFRP1'
'SFRP2'
'SH3PXD2B'
'SLC1A3'
'SLIT1'
'SLIT2'
'SLPI'
'SMAD3'
'SMARCA4'
'SMC3'
'SMOC1'
'SMOC2'
'SNCA'
'SOX9'
'SPARC'
'SPARCL1'
'SPINT1'
'SPINT2'
'SPOCK1'
'SPOCK3'
'SPON1'
'SPP1'
'SULF1'
'SULF2'
'TFF3'
'TFPI2'
'TGFB1'
'TGFB2'
'TGFB3'
'TGFBI'
'TGFBR1'
'TGFBR3'
'TGM2'
'THBS1'
'THBS2'
'THBS4'
'THSD4'
'TIMP1'
'TIMP3'
'TINAGL1'
'TLL1'
'TNC'
'TNFRSF11B'
'TNR'
'VCAM1'
'VCAN'
'VEGFA'
'VHL'
'VWA1'
'VWF'
'WISP1'
'WNT4'
'WNT5A'
'WNT7A'
'WNT7B'
'ZG16'
'ZP3'
'ACTN1'
'ADAM10'
'ADAM15'
'ADAM9'
'ADAMTS1'
'ADAMTS12'
'ADAMTS2'
'ADAMTS3'
'ADAMTS4'
'ADAMTS5'
'ADAMTS9'
'ADAMTSL1'
'ADAMTSL2'
'ADAMTSL3'
'AGRN'
'AP3M1'
'AP3M2'
'ARHGEF6'
'ASPN'
'ATL1'
'ATL2'
'ATL3'
'ATRN'
'ATRNL1'
'BGN'
'BMP1'
'BMP2'
'BMP4'
'BMPER'
'CAPN1'
'CAPN13'
'CAPN2'
'CAPN5'
'CAPN6'
'CD151'
'CD180'
'CD44'
'CEACAM1'
'CEACAM6'
'CEACAM8'
'CEP97'
'CHRDL1'
'CLEC11A'
'CNTNAP5'
'CNTRL'
'COL11A2'
'COL12A1'
'COL14A1'
'COL15A1'
'COL1A1'
'COL1A2'
'COL3A1'
'COL4A1'
'COL4A2'
'COL4A4'
'COL5A1'
'COL5A2'
'COL6A3'
'COLGALT2'
'CP'
'CPN2'
'CRIM1'
'CTGF'
'CTHRC1'
'CTSD'
'CTSK'
'CTSL'
'CTSO'
'CTSS'
'CTSV'
'CYR61'
'DCBLD2'
'DCN'
'DDR2'
'DLK1'
'DPT'
'DSP'
'ECM1'
'EDIL3'
'EFEMP1'
'EFEMP2'
'EGF'
'ELFN2'
'F5'
'FAM132A'
'FBLN1'
'FBLN5'
'FBN1'
'FERMT2'
'FGA'
'FGB'
'FGF2'
'FGG'
'FLNA'
'FLRT3'
'FMOD'
'FN1'
'FRAS1'
'FREM2'
'FRMPD1'
'FRMPD3'
'FRMPD4'
'FURIN'
'GAS6'
'GFOD2'
'HAPLN4'
'HEPH'
'HPX'
'HSPG2'
'HTRA1'
'ICAM1'
'ICAM2'
'IMPG2'
'ISLR'
'ITGA11'
'ITGA3'
'ITGA4'
'ITGA5'
'ITGA6'
'ITGA8'
'ITGAX'
'ITGB3'
'ITGB4'
'ITGB8'
'ITGBL1'
'JAM3'
'KDR'
'KLK7'
'KLKB1'
'L1CAM'
'LAMA2'
'LAMA3'
'LAMA4'
'LAMB1'
'LAMB2'
'LAMC1'
'LAMC2'
'LAMC3'
'LDLR'
'LDLRAD3'
'LGI1'
'LGI2'
'LGI3'
'LGR4'
'LGR5'
'LINGO2'
'LOX'
'LOXL2'
'LOXL3'
'LOXL4'
'LRFN2'
'LRFN3'
'LRFN4'
'LRFN5'
'LRG1'
'LRIG2'
'LRP1'
'LRP10'
'LRP12'
'LRP6'
'LRP8'
'LRRC17'
'LRRC19'
'LRRC32'
'LRRC37A5P'
'LRRC37B'
'LRRC4'
'LRRC49'
'LRRC9'
'LRRCC1'
'LRRIQ1'
'LRRIQ3'
'LRRN1'
'LRRN3'
'LRRTM2'
'LRRTM3'
'LRRTM4'
'LRTM1'
'LTBP1'
'LTBP2'
'LUM'
'MARCO'
'MBP'
'MEGF8'
'MEGF9'
'MEP1A'
'MEP1B'
'MFAP1'
'MFAP2'
'MFAP3'
'MFAP4'
'MFGE8'
'MGP'
'MME'
'MMP1'
'MMP10'
'MMP12'
'MMP14'
'MMP15'
'MMP16'
'MMP19'
'MMP2'
'MMP3'
'MMP7'
'MMP9'
'MMRN1'
'MMRN2'
'MSLN'
'MSR1'
'MUC5B'
'MUC6'
'MYOM1'
'NCAM1'
'NCSTN'
'NET1'
'NETO2'
'NID1'
'NID2'
'NOV'
'NPNT'
'NRP1'
'NRP2'
'NRXN1'
'NTN4'
'OGN'
'OPTC'
'OTOGL'
'OTOL1'
'P3H2'
'P4HA1'
'P4HA2'
'P4HA3'
'PARVB'
'PCOLCE'
'PCOLCE2'
'PDGFA'
'PECAM1'
'PGS1'
'PHYKPL'
'PIGN'
'PLG'
'PLOD1'
'PLOD2'
'PODN'
'POSTN'
'PTPRS'
'PXN'
'RSU1'
'SART1'
'SCARA3'
'SCUBE2'
'SDC1'
'SDC2'
'SELP'
'SENP7'
'SEPP1'
'SERPINE1'
'SERPINH1'
'SPARC'
'SPARCL1'
'SPOCK3'
'SPON1'
'SPP1'
'STRC'
'TGFB2'
'TGFB3'
'TGFBI'
'THBS1'
'THSD4'
'THSD7A'
'TIMP1'
'TIMP3'
'TKT'
'TLL1'
'TLR1'
'TLR2'
'TLR3'
'TLR5'
'TLR6'
'TLR9'
'TNC'
'TNFAIP6'
'TNR'
'TSKU'
'TTN'
'VASN'
'VCAM1'
'VCAN'
'VLDLR'
'VWC2L'
'WISP1'
'A2M'
'ADAM10'
'ADAMTS13'
'ADAMTS3'
'ADAMTS5'
'ADAMTS9'
'ADORA2B'
'AGT'
'AGTR1'
'AHSG'
'AKT1'
'ALOX15'
'ALPL'
'ANGPT1'
'ANGPTL2'
'ANGPTL4'
'ANXA2'
'APOE'
'APP'
'AR'
'ATP5B'
'ATP5O'
'BMP1'
'BMP2'
'BMP4'
'BMP7'
'CAPN1'
'CAPN2'
'CAT'
'CCL2'
'CD34'
'CD4'
'CD40'
'CD44'
'CDKN1A'
'CEBPB'
'CELA1'
'CFP'
'CHI3L1'
'CLU'
'CMA1'
'COL18A1'
'COL1A1'
'CPA6'
'CPB2'
'CST3'
'CTGF'
'CTNNB1'
'CTSB'
'CTSV'
'CXCL12'
'CXCL16'
'CXCL8'
'CXCR4'
'DCD'
'DEFA1'
'DPP4'
'DPP9'
'EDN1'
'ELANE'
'ELN'
'ENPP1'
'ERBB4'
'ERO1A'
'EZR'
'F2'
'F3'
'FAP'
'FASLG'
'FBLN1'
'FGB'
'FGF1'
'FGF2'
'FGF23'
'FGG'
'FLT4'
'FN1'
'FURIN'
'GAPDH'
'GAS6'
'GPER1'
'GPNMB'
'GSK3B'
'GZMB'
'HAS2'
'HGF'
'HIF1A'
'HMOX1'
'HPSE'
'HPSE2'
'HSPA5'
'HSPB1'
'HSPD1'
'HYAL1'
'ICAM1'
'IFNG'
'IGF1'
'IGFBP3'
'IGFBP5'
'IGFBP7'
'IL10'
'IL17A'
'IL1A'
'IL1B'
'IL1RL1'
'IL6'
'INHBA'
'ITGA1'
'ITGA2'
'ITGA2B'
'ITGAL'
'ITGAM'
'ITGB1'
'ITGB2'
'ITGB3'
'ITGB6'
'KDR'
'LAMA1'
'LGALS1'
'LGALS3'
'LGALS9'
'LINGO2'
'LMNA'
'LPL'
'LRP1'
'LRP5'
'LTF'
'MAP3K1'
'MAPK1'
'MAPK14'
'MAPK3'
'MAPT'
'MEF2C'
'MFGE8'
'MGP'
'MIR145'
'MIR21'
'MIR7-1'
'MMP1'
'MMP10'
'MMP12'
'MMP13'
'MMP14'
'MMP2'
'MMP3'
'MMP7'
'MMP8'
'MMP9'
'MSN'
'MSTN'
'MYH9'
'NDUFS3'
'NOS2'
'NOTCH3'
'NOX1'
'NPPB'
'NR1I2'
'NRG1'
'NRP1'
'OGN'
'OSM'
'PCSK9'
'PEA15'
'PECAM1'
'PGF'
'PIK3CA'
'PLAT'
'PLAUR'
'PLG'
'PLTP'
'PPARD'
'PRDX4'
'PRF1'
'PRKAA1'
'PRKCD'
'PRKCZ'
'PRSS1'
'PRSS2'
'PRTN3'
'PTEN'
'PTGS2'
'PTH'
'PVT1'
'RAC1'
'RAN'
'RARRES2'
'RDX'
'REG3A'
'ROCK2'
'RUNX2'
'S100A8'
'S100A9'
'SDC1'
'SERPINA1'
'SERPINE1'
'SERPINF1'
'SFTPD'
'SGCG'
'SHC1'
'SHH'
'SLC2A10'
'SMAD3'
'SMAD7'
'SOD1'
'SOD2'
'SOD3'
'SOST'
'SPARC'
'SPON2'
'SPP1'
'SRC'
'ST6GAL1'
'STK11'
'TEK'
'TFPI2'
'TGFB1'
'TGFBI'
'TGFBR1'
'TGFBR3'
'TGM2'
'THBS1'
'TIMP1'
'TIMP3'
'TLL1'
'TLR9'
'TMPRSS6'
'TNF'
'TNFRSF11B'
'TNFRSF1A'
'TNFRSF1B'
'TNFSF11'
'TNFSF12'
'TNFSF13'
'TP53'
'TP53INP2'
'TPSAB1'
'TTR'
'TWIST1'
'VASP'
'VCAM1'
'VEGFA'
'VTN'
'VWA2'
'VWF'
'WISP1'
'WNT5A'
'WNT5B'
'WWOX'
'ZEB1'
' AAA1'
' ABCC6'
' ACAN'
' ACG2'
' ACVRL1'
' ADAMTS1'
' ADAMTS7'
' ADAMTS9'
' ADIPOQ'
' AGER'
' AI1E'
' AMBN'
' ANGPT2'
' ANTXR2'
' APOE'
' APP'
' ARID1A'
' ARMD1'
' ATP2A2'
' ATS'
' BGLAP'
' BTHLM2'
' CASR'
' CAV1'
' CD44'
' CDA'
' CDGG1'
' CDKN1B'
' CDRB'
' CDTB'
' CFTR'
' CLEC3A'
' CLPX'
' CMM1'
' COH1'
' COL11A1'
' COL11A2'
' COL12A1'
' COL14A1'
' COL18A1'
' COL1A1'
' COL1A2'
' COL27A1'
' COL2A1'
' COL3A1'
' COL4A1'
' COL5A2'
' COL6A1'
' COL6A2'
' COL6A3'
' COL9A1'
' COMP'
' CRTAP'
' CTNNB1'
' CXCL12'
' CXCR1'
' CXCR2'
' DAG1'
' DDR1'
' DMD'
' DMD'
' DMP1'
' DSPP'
' ECM2'
' EDSMC1'
' EFEMP1'
' EFEMP2'
' EIF4A3'
' ELMO1'
' EMID2'
' FBLN1'
' FBLN5'
' FBN1'
' FERMT2'
' FGFR1'
' FGFR2'
' FGFR3'
' FN1'
' FOXC2'
' FREM1'
' HELLS'
' HP'
' IGAN1'
' IL1B'
' IL6'
' ITGB1'
' ITGB3'
' ITGB4'
' KAL1'
' KDR'
' KLK4'
' KNDLRS'
' LAD'
' LAMA2'
' LARGE'
' LDS2'
' LGMD2C'
' LMNA'
' LTBP4'
' MADA'
' MATN1'
' MDDGA4'
' MDDGC5'
' MFS'
' MGP'
' MJD'
' MMP1'
' MMP10'
' MMP11'
' MMP13'
' MMP14'
' MMP15'
' MMP16'
' MMP17'
' MMP2'
' MMP20'
' MMP24'
' MMP25'
' MMP3'
' MMP7'
' MMP8'
' MMP9'
' MORC3'
' MRC2'
' MTTL1'
' MVCD1'
' MXRA8'
' MYD88'
' NF1'
' NPR2'
' NTN1'
' NTRK2'
' OI13'
' OI2'
' OI7'
' PAX6'
' PDGFB'
' PKD1'
' PKD1'
' PSACH'
' PTEN'
' PTGS2'
' PTPRF'
' PXDN'
' RHOA'
' RUNX2'
' RUVBL1'
' SCN1B'
' SERPINB7'
' SERPINF1'
' SHH'
' SLC26A2'
' SLC2A10'
' SMA1'
' SMARCA2'
' SMARCA4'
' SMARCA5'
' SMARCB1'
' SMARCE1'
' SMN1'
' SNED1'
' SOD2'
' SPARC'
' SPG7'
' SPP1'
' SRRM1'
' ST14'
' STK11'
' TEK'
' TGFB1'
' TGFB2'
' TGFBI'
' TGFBR1'
' TGFBR2'
' THSD4'
' TIMP2'
' TLR2'
' TLR4'
' TNF'
' TNXB'
' TP53'
' UCMD1'
' UCP2'
' UCP3'
' USH2A'
' USH2C'
' VDR'
' VEGFA'
' VHL'
' VRNI'
' VWF'
' WBS'
' XFS'
' ZEB1'
' ZNF384'
```

Comment: Could you post your result with the data provided? I get a column sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: I edit the post @MayelaZamora

Comment: Remove the leading space in the elements of the cell array

Comment: Once you do that, process the output with unique(sortrows(output)).

Comment: How can I remove it Please? @MayelaZamora

Comment: Look into "strrep", for instance  strrep(' AR',' ', '') gives you 'AR'